# Django: Count forloop.first only if a second if condition is met

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following (oversimplified example):

```
{% for item in myitems  %}
  {% if item == "orange" %}
    {{item}}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Let's say that my list `myitems` is `['apple','orange','watermelon','orange']`. The above code prints twice "orange". But I don't want this... I would like to print it once. So then I tried using `if forloop.first`

```
{% for item in myitems  %}
  {% if item == "orange" %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
     {{item}}
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The first loop will be `item=apple` so it won't print the item because it is not "orange". In the second loop now we have `item=orange` but it no longer fulfills `if forloop.first` as it is the second loop already so it won't print the item. How can I print orange once? Is there a statement such us: `if forloop.first (start numbering from the first print)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can print the element of myitems only once when condition is met using a variable in the template and changing its value when the condition is met:

```
{% set stop_loop="" %}

{% for item in myitems  %}
    {% if stop_loop %}
    {% elif item == "orange" %}
        {{item}}
        {% set stop_loop="true" %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

IMO, this kind of business logics should be in the view rather than template.

Comment: not what I'm looking. All I want is that if the condition is fulfilled then print, but the condition is fulfilled multiple times so it will print several times. To avoid this I use forloop.first but the condition is not the first one of the for loop so it prints blank. I want to print it once even if the condition is fulfilled multiple times. any ideas?

Comment: I updated my question. I think is more clear now. somehow your solution doesn't print what I'm looking for

Comment: Thanks your solution helped a lot..but `set` is outdated I believe. I used `with` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I've correctly understood, you're basically looking for this piece of code:

```py
{% for item in myitems  %}
    {% if item == "orange" and forloop.first %}
        {{item}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

A simple `and` should do the job. With the example you provided `['apple','orange','watermelon']`, the rendered template would be blank.

Comment: It doesn't work. What I want is that if the if condition is fulfilled then print, but the condition is fulfilled multiple times so it will print several times. To avoid this I use forloop.first but the if condition is not the first one in the for loop so it prints blank. I want to print it once even if the condition is fulfilled multiple times. any ideas?

Comment: I'm still not sure to correctly understand what you want but are you certain you actually need a `for` loop? Why can't you simply use a condition such as `{% if "orange" in myitems %} ... {% endif %}`?

Comment: I can't because I don't know the value orange, I just know that it repeats..you can check my answer here, it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution based on previous comments

```
{% with False as stop_loop %}
{% for item in myitems  %}
    {% if stop_loop %}
    {% elif item == "orange" %}
        {{item}}
        {% update_variable True as stop_loop %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

And I need to register in `templatetags` the following:

```
@register.simple_tag
def update_variable(value):
    return value
```

It works